# Unexpected Plot3D behaviour

Tags: plotting, core-language

The following illustrates what appears to be an incorrect `Plot3D` for this polynomial. I have forced the function to complex argument, changed ranges. In contrast, `ListPLot3D` behaves as expected.

Is there something I am missing?

```
pol1 = x + 1 - x^2 - 2 + 3 x + 4 x^2;
pol2 = -2 Sqrt[x (1 - x^2)];
h[u_] := pol1^2 - pol2^2 /. x -> u
```

2D plots:

```
GraphicsColumn[{Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[h[x]]],
  Plot[Abs[h[x]], {x, -3, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[Abs@h[x]]]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

`Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[Abs@h[x + I y], {x, -3, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"Plot3D of ", TraditionalForm[Abs@h[z]]}]]
```

[image]

This appears to just be a translation of the real valued function along the y-axis and **not** the (or perhaps my) intended outcome...this can be easily confirmed by looking at adding even the smallest imaginary component to any of the 4 real roots.

In contrast `ListPlot3D`:

```
sol = Solve[h[x] == 0, x];
pts = {#, 0, 0} & /@ (x /. sol);
Show[ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, Abs@h[i + j I]}, {i, -3, 1, 0.1}, {j, -1, 1, 
     0.1}], 1], MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotRange -> {-1, 20}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.04], Point[pts]}], 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"ListPlot3D of ", TraditionalForm[Abs@h[z]]}]]
```

[image]

This nicely shows the four real roots and behaves as expected.

Comment: I don't have to parse it now but it seems you have some scoping problem there. Try `ClearAll[h]; Function[h[x_] := #^2 - #2^2][pol1, pol2]` to define `h`. Then it works for me like you want.

Comment: @Kuba thank you very much for such a prompt and clear response...a Homer Simpson...doh...

Comment: You can also do `h[u_] = pol1^2 - pol2^2 /. x -> u` in your definition of `h`, i.e. `Set`, rather than `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @kguler thanks `Evaluate` works either as option or function works...thanks

Comment: @MarkMcClure thank you learned a lot in the past few minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the option  `Evaluated->True`

```
Plot3D[Abs@h[x + I y], {x, -3, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"Plot3D of ", TraditionalForm[Abs@h[z]]}]
 Evaluated -> True]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something rather basic -- the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html). If you were to change your definition of `h` to use `Set`, all would be well.

```
pol1 = x + 1 - x^2 - 2 + 3 x + 4 x^2;
pol2 = -2 Sqrt[x (1 - x^2)];
h[u_] = (pol1^2 - pol2^2 /. x -> u);
Plot3D[Abs@h[x + I y], {x, -3, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Plot3D of ", TraditionalForm[Abs@h[z]]}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: yes as both kgulers `Evaluate` (forcing evaluation for a delayed setting) and MarkMcClure's comment have identified the pitfall of my penchant for `SetDelay` over `Set`...embarrassing but instructive lesson as they often are...have +1 your answer